# Is absolute value an one dimensional circle?

Tags: geometry

A circle is the set of all points that are at the same distance r from a given point in a plane (two dimensions). Similarly, a sphere is the set of all points that are at the same distance r from a given point in a three-dimensional space.

I know that in both cases, the elements of the set (the points composing the circle or sphere) are infinite. Let's say, for example in a circle, that you can take a point in the curve that is exactly at 60°, and take another on 61°, but you can also grab one more between 60° and 61° (60.5°). You can loop this infinite times (one between 60° and 60.5°, which is at 60.25°; another between 60.5° and 60.25°, at 60.125°, and so on...). **BUT**, if we limit ourselves to an one-dimensional space (a line), there would be just TWO points that satisfy the condition, and that results to be the absolute value of a number.

*...or am I wrong?*

Comment: To say that 'absolute value' is a geometric shape is misleading, but yes, any two points in one dimension are necessarily equidistant from another, and so they could be considered analogous to circles, spheres, etc.

Comment: Correct. The end points of a line segment share some likeness to a circle has. What you are getting at can be called a 0-sphere http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Answer (score 0):

There is a bijection between seminorms on a vector space and absorbing convex sets symmetric about zero. (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Classification_of_seminorms:_absolutely_convex_absorbing_sets), although the article is not very good.)

($A$ is convex if every point $z$ on the line segment joining two points $x,y \in A$ satisfies $z \in A$. Absorbing means that given any $x$ in the space, there is a number $a$ such that $x/a \in A$. Symmetric just means $x \in A \iff -x \in A$.)